# Enumerating through a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, enumerate

I am trying to enumerate through a dictionary like this but it does not work. What's the simplest way to iterate through a dictionary in python while enumerating each entry?

```
for i, k, v in enumerate(my_dict.iteritems()):
    print i, k, v
```

Comment: Note that the iteration order is [arbitrary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). Consider using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to iterate in insertion order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to add parenthesis around `(k, v)` tuple:

```
>>> d = {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
>>> for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
...     print i, k, v
...
0 1 foo
1 2 bar
```